# How to switch to the last added folder in that particular folder in S3 bucket

Tags: directory, date, cd-command, amazon-s3

I have a **S3 bucket in which starting of every month ... will be added. And in the month lder daily **new files will be added .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the current month directory on this way:

```
s3://project/js/Historical/$(date +%Y)/$(date +%b)
```

This will work if your locale is set to English and you have the name of the month with only 3 letters (first capital)!

To list the content use command:

```
aws s3 ls s3://project/js/Historical/$(date +%Y)/$(date +%b)
```

Here is your command:

```
aws s3 ls s3://project/js/Historical/$(date +%Y)/$(date +%b) | sort -rh | head -n 1 | awk {' print $2'}
```

If you want to have the full name of month do it on this way

```
aws s3 ls s3://project/js/Historical/$(date +%Y)/$(date +%m)_$(date +%B) | sort -rh | head -n 1 | awk {' print $2'}
```

If you have files creation for previous day you can use code like this:

```
aws s3 ls s3://project/js/Historical/$(date +%Y --date="1 day ago")/$(date +%m --date="1 day ago")_$(date +%B --date="1 day ago") | sort -rh | head -n 1 | awk {' print $2'}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89905/discussion-on-answer-by-romeo-ninov-how-to-switch-to-the-last-added-folder-in-th).